# The maximum number of solution to $f(x)=y$ in $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : (0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable function such that $f'$ has finitely many zeros in $(0,1)$ and $f'$ changes sign at exacttly two of these points. Then for any $y\in \mathbb{R}$ The maximum number of solution to $f(x)=y$ in $(0,1)$ is $3$.
[image]

If $x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_9$ are zeros of $f'(x)$ then the following graph is one of the possibility where the derivative is changing the sign at $x_2$ and $x_5$. But how to use this idea to conclude that **The maximum number of solution to $f(x)=y$ in $(0,1)$ is $3$.**

Comment: You drew a graph of $f'$, not $f$, and ignored the fact that $f$ may only be defined on $(0,1)$ because the graph extends to negative $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** I didn't notice to that part saying $f'$ changes sign at exactly two points. In this case $f$ has most $3$ solution for $f(x) =y$, because other wise if $f(x) =y$ has $4$ solutions then according to Role theorem $f'$ has $3$ consecutive zeros (at least  3 !) such that all are local extreme Points(Min/Max/Min/  for example) Lets call them $x_1 < x_2 < x_3 $ and this  requires $f'$ changes sign Three times at $x_i$, which is a contradiction!

And $f(x) =0$ can have exactly $3$ solutions, Take

$$f(x) = x (x-1)(x-2)$$

Following is wrong!

Hint: First note that  for any function, If $f'$ has $n$ zeros then $f$ has at most $n+1$  zeros,  and this bound can be attained , just try a function like what you wrote above !

Substituting $f$ with $f-y$ you have at most $n+1$ solutions for $f(x) = y$

Comment: But it is not asking about the zeros of $f$ but the solution of $f(x)=y$.

Comment: Is it clear Now? I just wanted to give hint, not whole story! @SachchidanandPrasad

Comment: Okay, sorry. Got it.

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad  Sorry I Edited my answer!